# How to select appropriate binding and other http attributes?

Tags: authentication, certificate, x509, ws-security, wshttpbinding

I am working on an C# application (in Visual Studio 2013) that is to send documents to a state agency.  My company has other similar programs sending documents to other states, and I have used one of them as a starting point.   I am not at all sure, however, if the items such as binding type are appropriate.

The state provides a brief technical guide detailing how we are to communicate with their system.  I assume a http communications expert could read that and from experience tell right away the type of binding - and everything else - that is needed.  This is my first such project, and so I am not sure.

So, my question is, given their technical description, how do I determine what type of binding, and what values to use for the various attributes in the app.config file ?

One of the 'services' their system supports is a Ping command.  I am now working on a dirt simple program to use their ping command, just trying to get the basic communications working.   I also have a Ping request setup in SoapUI, and have successfully used that to send the message to the state system and get a response.  So, it would appear I have the certificates set up properly.

I copied the relevant sections of the technical guide below, and can give a little background:

I have their WSDL,
I know the ETIN number, username and password,
Submissions refers to documents my company sends to the state,
Gateway/treasury refers to the state system,
Transmitter refers to my company.

From technical guide:

> It is an application-to-application (A2A) transmission of data,
>   completely automated, with no manual intervention.
>
> Submissions must be transmitted to and from the Gateway server using
>   TLS technology.  This type of transmission provides secure data
>   exchange by strongly encrypting the data stream in both directions
>   according to the TLS protocol.  TLS is the only supported version for
>   secure communication; Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) is no longer
>   accepted.
>
> The Gateway conforms to standard http protocols.  The Gateway provides
>   service for SOAP transmissions over a TLS connection using the HTTPS
>   post protocol.  All transmissions or requests to the Gateway occur in
>   a single request-response https session.
>
> A SOAP message contains one SOAP header and one SOAP body within one
>   SOAP envelope.  SOAP header contains the WS-Security and State Header
>   elements.
>
> WS-Security provides transport-neutral mechanisms to send security
>   tokens as part of a message, to provide message integrity, and support
>   message confidentiality.  Specifically, this specification defines a
>   standard set of SOAP extensions used when building secure Web Services
>   to implement message content integrity and confidentiality.
>
> The Gateway will provide a Strong Authentication where transmitters
>   are authenticated via ETIN number,  X.509 Certificates and Treasury
>   assigned user code and password.  The X.509 Certificate will be used
>   for client-side authentication in an HTTPS connection to Treasury’s
>   servers.  Treasury accepts self-signed certificates as well as those
>   purchased from a trusted source.
>
> Transmitters must provide their HTTPS Client Authentication X.509
>   Certificate to Treasury via email to --------.  Treasury’s public key
>   certificate will be made available on the Software Developer Secure
>   Web Site at --------.  Transmitter’s X.509 Certificates for
>   client-side HTTPS authentication should only be valid for one year. 
>   Username/Password and HTTPS Client-Side authentication and
>   authorization will happen during every request to the Gateway.

So - given this, how do I know what binding type to use, and the other critical attribute values ?

I'm not expecting anyone to explain to me every detail of the program I should create, or the entire app.config file, rather I am looking for suggestions on the basics I need to get started.

Thanks